# How to determine whether some proces is inserting in database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to extract data from a database. I have only datareader on this specific database. Another department is responsible for filling this database. However, they do not always communicate when they are updating this database. Agreeing on a schedule has been proven pointless. This causes frequent problems (deadlocks, incomplete data) when I read data from this database. Is there some way (preferably through TSQL) to find out if they are mutating that database? This way I can build a check in my SSIS procedure that reschedules my package if they are mut(il)ating that database.

(And yes, I do realise that this should not be solved by technical procedures but by cooperation but I am strongly pushed to build a 'detection mechanism' )

Comment: Get permissions to exec `sp_who2` and process the results.

Comment: Or use a higher transaction isolation level in your querying combined with mindful transaction usage.

Comment: Another job step which is performed when your main step with ssis fails and updates schedule/enables/disables some additional schedule on selfsame job.

Comment: How does the other team update the database? SSIS, Excel, T/SQL an application?

Comment: If I can offer an out of the box idea: if you are only reading, you could [create a snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms175158) and query that instead (requires Enterprise). Closely related (and available in more editions) is using [snapshot isolation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/tcbchxcb).

Comment: In general, if they are responsible for producing a *complete* set of the data, the problem is unsolvable because you will never be able to detect, at any point in time, if the data is now really complete or if they're "going to" do another insert "in just a few moments now". I suppose you could try one of the techniques [described here](https://sqlblog.org/2008/05/06/when-was-my-database-table-last-accessed) to see when the database was last accessed, but that's still fairly unreliable.

Comment: One approach could be to add one more column to database  which tells you who inserted data (suser_sname())

Comment: Also, if deadlocks are at least a way of detecting if things have failed, you can use `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW` to ensure your queries are always the deadlock victims and not any of the processes updating the database (though, typically, SQL Server will favor read queries for victimization anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Regarding the deadlocks**: If you're reading from an [OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing) datastore you would typically do so with "*SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;*". This is often implemented at the select level as "*...WITH ( NOLOCK )...*", but doing it at the stored procedure level is preferable if you are using procedures.

**Regarding the incomplete data**: In your select statement you should implement joins that would exclude partial data. For example; if a user name of "John Smith" is being inserted into a highly normalized schema and the (new) names "John" and "Smith" have been inserted into a table "*[user].[name] ([id] [int], [name] nvarchar);*", but a corresponding record hadn't been inserted into a table "*[user].[full_name] ([first] [int], [last] [int]);*", you would inner join the two tables so you would not get the new names of "John" and "Smith" as there is no corresponding record in the "*[full_name]*" table.

Comment: Using `UNCOMMITTED` is OK only as long as you don't care about the accuracy of your data (say, it's a monitoring query that's executed every 5 minutes anyway). An SSIS package probably doesn't fit that bill.

Comment: I should have qualified my answer more. However, I wouldn't use statement that I "don't care about the accuracy" of the data. READ UNCOMMITTED is a legitimate tool if used properly.

Comment: I'm not saying *you personally* don't care about the accuracy of your data. I'm saying `READ UNCOMMITTED` should only be used in cases where you truly can afford the risk that the results of the query can be very wrong. Aside from reading data that hasn't been committed, [rows can be read twice, or not at all](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andrew_kelly/archive/2009/04/10/how-dirty-are-your-reads.aspx). If your data is not being modified, or the results are transient anyway, it's not an issue. If you have an OLTP *and* a need for accuracy, do it a favor and consider snapshot isolation.

Comment: I agree. Again, I should have qualified my original answer further. Snapshot isolation is a good tool in this case.